# How to manipulate circular progress bar with animation attribute using Javascript? Rails 5.2

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change the state of a circular progress bar, and then save the value of it in a rails hidden_form attribute, to keep track of the changes. The twist is that the progress bar is using an animation attribute & class called loading, in which uses -webkit-transform: rotate(deg). The overall progression will be linked to the total amount of filled form inputs. So, if 30 out of 100 form inputs are not empty. It will show 30% as the progress-value and 30% of the bar will be filled out of 100%. The values will be retrieved from the database when the user is editing the form.

I tried to alter the state of the progress bar within the JS console, but I couldn't figure out which approach I should take.

```
<!-- Progress Bar -->
  <div class="progress blue">
                <span class="progress-left">
                    <span class="progress-bar"></span>
                </span>
              <span class="progress-right">
                    <span class="progress-bar"></span>
                </span>
              <div class="progress-value">90%</div>
            </div>

<!-- CSS -->

.progress {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  background: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: none;
  position: relative;
}

.progress:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 12px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.progress > span {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progress .progress-left {
  left: 0;
}

.progress .progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: none;
  border-width: 12px;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.progress .progress-left .progress-bar {
  left: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 80px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 80px;
  border-left: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
  transform-origin: center left;
}

.progress .progress-right {
  right: 0;
}

.progress .progress-right .progress-bar {
  left: -100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 80px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 80px;
  border-right: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center right;
  transform-origin: center right;
  animation: loading-1 1.8s linear forwards;
}

.progress .progress-value {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #44484b;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 135px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
}

.progress.blue .progress-bar {
  border-color: #049dff;
}

.progress.blue .progress-left .progress-bar {
  animation: loading-2 1.5s linear forwards 1.8s;
}

@keyframes loading-2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg); // test values
    transform: rotate(144deg); // test values
  }
}


<!-- JavaScript -->
let progress_bar = document.getElementsByClassName('loading-2');
if ($("#full_name").val().length > 0) progress_bar.style.transform(+= 0.05deg);

<!-- Rails input -->
<%= f.input :full_name, class: 'form-control', input_html: {id: "full_name"} %> 

<%= f.input :current_progress, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => totalProgressInteger } %>
When a form input field value is changed, the circular progress bar will either decrease/increase in length, and the current value of the form will be saved when the user commits the form.
```

Comment: Why do you want to save the progress bar value ? You can find this value from the fields that have been filled from your form. Your Rails controller can do that and return to the view an instance variable like `@filled` set to a value between 0 and 100. Then you have to identify what CSS values have to be changed to make a change in the animation and populate this/these values directly into your view using html option `style` (because CSS are static assets you can't make your css file an `css.erb` file and use `@filled` directly in your css file, eventhough this is theoretically possible)

Comment: In case you want to progress bar to start from it's previous value, instead of starting from 0 degree, then you are correct you need to store the current progress value, so that you can compare it to the new progress value that you can anyway obtain through your form/fields completion. (though I would say this is really cosmetic, as starting animation from 0 degree does not seem to be real problem)

Comment: This is a fairly large form. It has 5-6 nested forms. So, I have no choice but to do it inside of the view.